"Check Gas Cap" warning - 2006 pontiac pursuit
A few weeks ago I got a "Check Gas Cap" warning on the display of my pursuit. This was later accompanied by a check engine light. I then swapped my gas cap for an aftermarket one - the engine light went away after a few days.
However, now I am still occasionally getting the "Check Gas Cap" warning on the display.
Any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Is 'check gas cap' the actual error or are you assuming the error code points only to a loose gas cap? P0455 is one of several emissions errors but doesn't point to the gas cap.  What is the error code? My guess is you'll have to review the entire evaporative emissions plumbing, possibly corroded metal fuel  vent line, pinhole leak in metal or rubber hose, etc.
